# How to make a clean URL of this (htaccess URL rewrite)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use a support system and I want to rewrite the URLs to make them more SEO friendly and better readable. I have very basic understanding of .htaccess rewrite rules / regex and I tried a hundred things, but could not get it working.

The support system is installed on this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/help/
```

The code is generating this URL for every article in the KB:

```
http://www.example.com/help/index.php?/selfhelp/view-article/article-1
```

The code is generating this URL for the category overview within the KB:

```
http://www.example.com/hulp/index.php?/selfhelp/categories
```

How can I rewrite those URLs to something readable and SEO friendly like:

```
http://www.example.com/help/article/article-1
```

And for categories:

```
http://www.example.com/hulp/categories
```

If this is even possible? And if so, how can I do this using .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can make the friendly URLs work like this, and also redirect the old URLs:

```
# Rewrite new URLs
RewriteRule ^help/article/(.+)$ help/index.php?/selfhelp/view-article/$1 [E=rewritten:1]
RewriteRule ^help/categories$ help/index.php?/selfhelp/categories [E=rewritten:1]

# Redirect old URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/selfhelp/view-article/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^help/index\.php$ /help/article/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =/selfhelp/categories
RewriteRule ^help/index\.php$ /help/categories [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, this is great and does work! 2 more questions however:

- Some scripts goes missing when using the simplified article URL. If I check the console, it is trying to retrieve scripts via: /help/article/script/jquery.js where using the old URL it is retrieving the script via /help/script/jquery.js. Can I make exception for JS and CSS files or something like that?

- Other question is, can I force my URLs to use the nice URL's, or should I just change my scripts so they use the nice URL from now on? (I want to omit editing the code as max as possible since it is third-party software)

Comment: Never mind the first question. I understand that the source code is using relative url's, and since my URL is now relative to help/article instead of help/ it wil fail loading the files. I will just edit the source code to fix this. Still curious about the second question! Thanks!

Comment: The easiest thing to do is change your scripts so they are referenced with absolute URLs. You're using relative URLs at the moment which is causing the problem. Just Google those terms to learn more if you need. So change the reference to your scripts to be like '/help/script/jquery.js' instead of 'script/jquery.js'. It's not that this is messing with it, just that it's being loaded relative to the current URL instead of referenced from root.

Comment: Yes exactly, glad you worked it out. Will leave comment there for others.

Comment: For using the nice URLs properly, yes, you have to change the software to generate URLs with them. The old URLs could be redirected, but it's not the way to do it, you want them generated that way on the pages. You might want to also redirect the old URLs.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it's helpful for you. Let me know if you want code for redirecting the old URLs. Can be useful if they are in the search engine results, so Google etc  pick up on the new URLs properly.

Comment: Hi, if you can give the code for that I would be very grateful! The URLs indeed are indexed in Google and on some websites people have put links to those URLs.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That should do it. Includes an update to the original rules to avoid a loop. Let me know any problems.